# How to make sure my Excel add-in does not load CLR for .NET Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

Given that Microsoft is going to stop support for .NET Framework 2.0, I want to make sure my excel addin does not use .net framework 2.0.

I have recompiled my main add-in using .NET Framework 4.0 but I have few utility assemblies that, were compiled using .NET Framework 2.0, still referenced by the main add-in (I am not able to recompile these referenced DLLs as I have lost the source code for these ones).

I am not sure how the binding of these referenced DLLs works.

Do these DLLs use .NET runtime 4.0 the same as the target runtime of main add-in or do they use the runtime for which they were compiled?

When I run `clrver '<Excel Process ID>'` - it tells me that the process is running both .NET Framework 2.0 and 4.0.

Well, I have many other add-ins on the system and I am not sure which ones use what runtime version.

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Support for 2.0 ended in 2011. It ended for 4.0 in January of this year. You are not ahead of this curve, 4.5.2 is the oldest one still supported. Clrver doesn't tell you what other add-ins might be used, the in-process side-by-side versioning feature of CLR v4 allows both. And it doesn't tell you anything about the framework version, only the runtime version (like 4.0.30919).  So it is quite useless.  Target at least 4.5.2 and leave it up to IT staff to figure out what else is getting loaded.

Comment: well, i also checked modules/dlls loaded using process explorer, it shows both version on .net runtime - mscorwks.ddl and clr.dll. I want to make sure my addin is not responsible for loading mscorwks - i dont want to leave it to IT staff.